# How do I make a section of an activity always-on-top?

Tags: android, layout, always-on-top

Had a question about making part of a View Always-On-Top. Please see the Groupon picture below. The black window at the bottom where it says "From $29" & "Buy!" is always on top of the activity page. Meaning the rest of the page is scrollable above that black window at the bottom. **Please note I only want this activity to have an Always-On-Top**

[image]

How do I make a portion of the activity Always On Top? And what kind of layout did you think they used for Groupon? I was just going to make a `RelativeLayout` and `layout_alignParentBottom="true"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably get away with having a vertical linear layout with two children. The first one a scrollable area and the bottom a view with whatever it is you want to be 'on top'. Since there's no transparency there's no visual difference between having the black view as always-on-top and having one view on top of the other (in the y-axis, not z-axis). Plus, if you do it this way you can reach and see the bottom of the scrollable view's content.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, the best way to do this is by implementing a BaseActivity with this View, and have all your activities extend this activity instead of the standard Activity.